# Looping through two cell ranges in two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, integer, range

The following code runs but, not getting the results. The information is there in the correct range.

```
Dim ID As Range
Dim SN As Range
Dim i As Integer
   Set ID = Sheet6.Range("B2:B8")
   Set SN = Sheet2.Range("C7:C184")
   For i = 2 To ID.Cells.count
      If ID.Cells(i) = SN.Cells(i) Then
         MsgBox "do something"
         ID.Cells.Offset(0, 2).Value = SN.Cells.Offset(0, -2).Value
         Else
        MsgBox "sorry"
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: Step through and see what the values are? Not sure we can answer this as we don't know what results you are getting or what results you are looking for.

Comment: Im getting the msgbox " sorry" when i should be getting msgbox "do something"
in the step out ID cells gives me the correct value and the SN cells gives me the same value.

Comment: Something is definitely different between them, if they are dates perhaps one has time too. If they are numbers the formatting might be truncating decimals, if they are text there might be whitespace before or after etc...

Comment: The problem is here: 
 'If ID.Cells(i) = SN.Cells(i) Then'
they seem to be searching the same range.

Comment: So `ID.Cells(i)` will be B3 Through B8 on Sheet 6 and `SN.Cells(i)` will be C8 through C13 on Sheet 2. Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: SN.Cells will be C7 through C184 on sheet2

Comment: It will not be because you are looping through from 2 to how many cells are in the range ID which is 7. indexing a range from 2 means you skip the first range, so it will never be C7 and will never go beyond C13 as you have it.

Answer (score -1):

i found another code and modified it to my work sheet. This one works great.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For i = 2 To 40
    If Sheet6.Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
Exit For
    End If
For j = 7 To 1000
    If Sheet2.Range("c" & j).Value = "" Then
Exit For
    End If
        If Sheet6.Range("C" & i).Text = Sheet2.Range("c" & j).Text Then
            Sheet6.Range("C" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("c" & j).Offset(0, -2).Value
             Sheet6.Range("C" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value = Sheet2.Range("c" & j).Offset(0, 2).Value
           Exit For
         End If
Next j
Next i
```